# Open fragment from inside fragment without previous fragment UI appearing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to open a fragment (PageFragment) from inside a fragment (UpcomingFragment).

When I open the fragment, the previous fragment UI is still present and I would not like this to be so.

I have tried both .getSupportFragmentManager(), and GetChildFragmentManager() neither of these solve the problem.And looking through simular thread on here, and I can't get a working result.

```java
mRecyclerAdapter.setItemClickListener(new CardOnClicked() {
    @Override
    public void onCardClicked(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Test");

        Fragment pageView = new PageFragment();


        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.frag, pageView);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();


    }
});
```

You can find my Github repository here:

https://github.com/KyleGwynDavies/aTV

You can see the problem here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp9Kz.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two fragments should never communicate directly. All communication needs to be done through the host activity. For that use an Interface.

**Create an interface:**

```
public interface IMainActivity {
void navigateFragment(); 
}
```

**Add interface to the adapter override onAttachedToRecyclerView:**

```
private IMainActivity mInterface;

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    //instantiate interface when view attach to the recycler view
    mInterface = (IMainActivity) mContext;
}

holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mInterface.navigateFragment();
        }
    });
```

**Finally, implement interface from to MainActivity and override the method then add your fragment.**

```
 @Override
public void navigateFragment() {
    mViewProfileFragment = new ViewProfileFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.main_content_frame, mViewProfileFragment, getString(R.string.tag_fragment_view_profile));
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer, would you be willing to explain a little more why this is, I've tried to read the documents from Google, and I've found a little diffcuilut to comprehend.